# React Native componentDidMount lifecycle performance issue

Tags: react-native, lifecycle

I'm using componentDidMount asynchronously like:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const res0 = await fetch('something')
  const res1 = await fetch('somethingElse')
}
```

and was wondering if this is causing any performance issues or it is bad practice and there is a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes. You can do this.**

`componentDidMount` is itself built for making `API` requests, so using `async` / `await` is no harm.

I'd suggest you to don't do this. We should never change / alter what is already defined.

Instead you can create a separate `async` function and call that function in `componentDidMount`.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchData();
}
```

And the function should be,

```
fetchData = async () => {
  const res0 = await fetch('something')
  const res1 = await fetch('somethingElse')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, that's how im going to do it.